# Add multiple values to one key in dictionary with for loop

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop

I'm using a similar method in a function I'm using. Why do I get a key error when I try to do this?

```
def trial():
     adict={}
     for x in [1,2,3]:
          for y in [1,2]:
               adict[y] += x
print(adict)
```

Comment: You try to add something to `adict[y]` with `adict[y] += x`, but `adict[y]` isn't defined the first time you try to access the key.

Answer (score 1):

`adict` starts off empty. You can't add an integer to a value that doesn't already exist.

Comment: To elaborate, your in-place `adict[y] += x` line is the issue. There's nothing already "in-place" on the first pass.

Answer (score 1):

You did not initialize `adict` for each key. You can use `defaultdict` to solve this issue:

```
from collections import defaultdict
def trial():
    adict=defaultdict(int)
    for x in [1,2,3]:
        for y in [1,2]:
            adict[y] += x
    print(adict)
trial()
```

The result is `defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {1: 6, 2: 6})`

Answer (score 0):

There is no value assigned to `adict[y]` when you first use it.

```
def trial():
     adict={}
     for x in [1,2,3]:
          for y in [1,2]:
               if y in adict: # Check if we have y in adict or not 
                   adict[y] += x
               else: # If not, set it to x
                   adict[y] = x
     print(adict)
```

Output:

```
>>> trial()
{1: 6, 2: 6}
```

Comment: No, `adict[y]` is not `None`, it doesn't exist. These are two diffferent things.

Answer (score 0):

You should modify youre code like this:

```
def trial():
   adict={0,0,0}
   for x in [1,2,3]:
      for y in [1,2]:
           adict[y] += x
print(adict)
```

"adict" has no entries. So adict[1] fails because it is accessing a variable that does not exist.